# How to increase Dots size in rectangle

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.drawing

How to increase the white dots sizes? Please refer the attached image.
How to increase dot size to bigger size? I have tried multiple ways to increase size of the dots

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
//Image image = new Bitmap(1000, 1000, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Green);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
graph.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
Brush b = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.Percent90, Color.Orange, Color.White);
// Fill rectangle to screen.
graph.FillRectangle(b, rect);
bitmap.Save("myImage.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

[image]

```
How to increase dot size to bigger size?
```

Comment: Presumably change the `HatchStyle.Percent90` to something else.  Specifically `Percent90` makes the foreground color (orange) 90% of the output.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchstyle?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#fields.  Alternatively, you may have to render the dots yourself instead of relying on `HatchBrush`.

Comment: I think you are asking how to make the white dots cover more pixels. You can create a smaller image and in the end scale it up. If you scale it 2× then the white dots will be 2× bigger.